# How to set the default sort order of primeng table depending on observable value

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have `p-table` with sortable columns. However, initially I want the table to be sorted by a specific column, I use `sortFiled` for that. But this column is not known till run-time.
Here is a snippet of the table:

```
<p-table [value]="offers" sortField="totalPrice">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
       <tr>
          <th pSortableColumn="shopName">Name
              <p-sortIcon field="shopName"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
          <th pSortableColumn="unitPrice">Unit price
              <p-sortIcon field="unitPrice"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
          <th pSortableColumn="totalPrice">Total price
              <p-sortIcon field="totalPrice"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
       </tr>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template pTemplate="body"> .... </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

I need to specify the column depending on the value of an observable, something like the following but that doesnt seem to work.

```
 <p-table [value]="offers" sortField="(isRelventPrice$ | async)? totalPrice : unitPrice">
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: sortField requires a string and it looks like you're passing in variables. Will it work if you make the totalPrice and unitPrice as strings?
`<p-table [value]="offers" sortField="(isRelventPrice$ | async)? 'totalPrice' : 'unitPrice'">`

Comment: this will solve your problem `[sortField]="(isRelventPrice$ | async)? 'totalPrice' : 'unitPrice'"` 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortField` is the current selected filtered column and will be updated in case of any value change.

you can set it as simple string

```html
<p-table [value]="offers" sortField="totalPrice">...<p-table>
```

in case of data binding you need to use `curly brackets []`

```html
<p-table [value]="offers" [sortField]="totalPriceValue">...<p-table>
```

and for you case isRelventPrice$ this will work

```html
 <p-table 
    [value]="offers" [sortField]="(isRelventPrice$ | async)? 'totalPrice' : 'unitPrice'">
....
</p-table>
```

check this [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesort-demo-jk9nou?file=src/app/app.component.html)

[**angular binding syntax**](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax)

Comment: I was playing around with the demo but when I specify for the [sortField] category, quantity or price the order is not correct.